# Asynctask doesn't stop after cancelling it in doInBackground

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to code a progress bar, that increases depending on a timer (starts at 0 and goes up to a certain time I choose).
When I click on a button, the progress bar decreases (decreases from values[0] - 5).
When the progress bar value is 30, I want to stop the progressbar, so stop asynctask, and restart it so the progress bar value is now 0.

My code doesn't have any error, the problem is that the progressbar doesn't stop and doesn't restart. (I know that because I made a TOAST to print the value of the progress bar, and it never stops)

This is my code in MainActivity

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
ProgressBar progressBar_eau;

TextView txt;
int compteur = 0;

Button btn_arrosoir; 

MyTask task_eau;
Boolean restart = true;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn_arrosoir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_arrosoir);//my button when you click the progress bar decreases
    progressBar_eau = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.barre_eau);
    progressBar_eau.setMax(30);
    Drawable draw3=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_eau);
    progressBar_eau.setProgressDrawable(draw3);

    progressBar_eau.setProgress(0);

    task_eau = new MyTask(progressBar_eau);
    task_eau.execute(300);

    btn_arrosoir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //OnCLick Stuff
            compteur = compteur - 5;

        }
    });

}


public void cancelAsynctask(){
    if (restart == false){
        task_eau.cancel(true);
        restartAsynctask();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        restart = true;
    }

}

public void restartAsynctask(){
    task_eau = new MyTask(progressBar_lumiere);
            task_eau.execute(300);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "restart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//my emulator shows both message start and restart even though the progress bar doesn't stop
}

public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {

    ProgressBar progressBar_actuelle;
    public MyTask(ProgressBar target) {
        progressBar_actuelle = target;

    }


     @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {


            while (task_eau.isCancelled() == false){
                for (; count <= params[0]; count++) {

                    try {
                     Thread.sleep(1000);
                                                publishProgress(count);

                                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                }
                }

                return null;
            }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }



    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

        progressBar_actuelle.setProgress(values[0]+compteur);

        if (progressBar_actuelle.getProgress() >= 30){
            restart = false;
            cancelAsynctask();
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the Progressbar declared in AsyncTask.Remove that and directly use the progressbar object created in onCreate method.I also observed that you are not dismissing progressbar at any point in the code. Look into it as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! The reason I declared a progressBar in Asynctask is because after, I want to use 3 different progressbar, that will decrease all within a different time. So I want to call each of them separately. It's true I haven't dismissed my progress bar, but how do I do that ?

Comment: Actually I don't want to dismiss the progress bar because at the end, when asynctask stop, I want it to restart so the progress bar restart decreasing...